# JSP, Javascript, getting ElementId within another Id

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, websphere-portal, websphere-7

my question today revolves arround the world of javascript in a Websphere JSP environment...

I have a code that is somewhat like this:

```
<div id="randomDynamicId">
    <input id="whatIwantToGetTo">
</div>
```

I know that I could just look for that id directly, but this is in a Websphere portal, I "should" be able to link to it directly by document.getElementById(), but I always need to acquire the id of the prior div. 
(it ends up being the portlet id with the namespace and since sometimes these portlets might be replicated I want to target just one specifically)

Any way that I might be able to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your code is being replicated such that you're getting multiple nested `<input>` elements with the same "id" value, that's bad. On any given page, the values of "id" attributes must all be **unique**; that's what makes them **identifiers**.

Comment: @Goncalo: I think the question is a bit unclear. What is it that you want to do? Is the issue that `whatIwantToGetTo` is not namespace-prefixed so that you end up with multiple elements with the same `id` on your page? In that case, rewrite your JSP to namespace all `id` attributes as well. (Which you should do anyway, _at the very least_ if there is a possibility of the portlet occurring more than once on _any_ page!)

Comment: @Gustav, well it does generate the namespace for the outter div ids and classes, not yet for the inputs, not at this point anyway, and I really don't think it will be added anytime soon (am at a prototype stage). but Thanks for clearing that up, with the namespace and the added id I should be able to easilly access it!

please Add this as an Answer and not as a comment as I'd like to give you credit for it.

Comment: Aren't you *actually* using JSF? Yes? Just give the component and its parent `UINamingContainer` components a fixed `id`. It'll end up like as `parentId:inputId`. Look in the generated HTML source yourself.

Comment: @BalusC well the thing is, this is IBM Portal Server...
I can't give a fixed ID to the outer divs, and if some "maniac" decides to have two instances of the same Portlet showing up in the same page...
well the code I did for this would mess up everywhere.

I did however end up using the namespace retrieval that the portal server gives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your request I post my earlier comment as an answer, a little more elaborated: If the issue is that `whatIwantToGetTo` is not namespace-prefixed so that you end up with multiple elements with the same id on your page, you should rewrite your JSP to namespace all `id` attributes as well. This should probably be done anyway (if you *can* modify the HTML, that is), at the very least if there is a possibility of the portlet occurring more than once on any page!

However, seeing as you're on a WebSphere Portal 7, you most likely have Dojo around and you could leverage its CSS-style selector mechanism like so:

```
var inputElement = dojo.query('#randomId > input');
```

Comment: yeah, dojo did actually save me, the problem was I had to find the namespace, run a substring limiter on the namespace data I got and then search for all id's and classes (since in some instances of websphere portal, it adds classes instead of ids) for that given name (with namespace added to it)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
document.getElementById ('whatIwantToGetTo').parentNode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, you can accomplish this like so:

```
var parent = $('#whatIwantToGetTo').parent();
```

[See Here](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

The pure javascript alternative is something like this:
alert(document.getElementById('objectIWant').parentNode.id);

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/yBJ32/)